# CanExecute in Prism DelegateCommand not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, prism

When I click on the button a few times in short time, the method is called every time and my app crashes (when code tries to navigate to another page). This problem occurs only in Xamarin.Android (iOS deals with double click)

```
public bool IsBusy { get; set; }

private DelegateCommand<string> _eventDetailsCommand;
public DelegateCommand<string> EventDetailsCommand => _eventDetailsCommand ?? (_eventDetailsCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(EventDetails, (x) => !IsBusy));

private void EventDetails(string obj)
{
    IsBusy = true;
    await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("AnotherPage");
    IsBusy = false;
}
```

Xamarin.Android

Prism: 7.1.0.172 (pre)

PropertyChanged.Fody (2.2.6):

Comment: Even though it's obvious what's wrong here, you should edit your question to expand on _what exactly is not working_ and _what you expect your code to do_...

Comment: yes, you're right

Answer (score 1):

the most important point is **DelegateCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged**

you should first set CanNavigate to false and the button will be disabled, after the button command method code done then set it be true

this is my example, it's working fine:

```
    private bool _canNavigate = true;
    public bool CanNavigate
    {
        get { return _canNavigate; }
        set { 
            SetProperty(ref _canNavigate, value);
            LoginCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    private DelegateCommand _loginCommand;
    public DelegateCommand LoginCommand => _loginCommand ?? (_loginCommand = new DelegateCommand(Login, () => CanNavigate));
    public async void Login()
    {
        CanNavigate = false;
        
        ...do something here

        CanNavigate = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> private void EventDetails(string obj)
>   {
>       IsBusy = true;
>       ....
>       IsBusy = false;
>   }

This blocks the UI thread for the whole time of the execution of the event handler, therefore neither `IsBusy = true;` nor `IsBusy = false;` have any observable effect on the ui.

This is a textbook example for `async`.

You should write something like this:

```
private async void EventDetails(string obj)
{
    IsBusy = true;

    await ....;

    IsBusy = false;
}
```

If `....` happens not to be awaitable, wrap it in `Task.Run`:

```
private async void EventDetails(string obj)
{
    IsBusy = true;

    await Task.Run( () => .... );

    IsBusy = false;
}
```

Comment: I called await NavigationService.NavigateAsync() in place of dots to navigate to another page

Comment: Please clarify what you expect your code to do. If I remember correctly `NavigateAsync` starts the navigation, and awaiting it will just wait for the navigation to start not until the navigation is completed, but I may be wrong.

Comment: My code should navigate to another page by Prism's navigation service. But now, during double click on listview item my app crashes, because the command is called twice (this behavior occurs only on Android)

Comment: You might be right, that problem is connected with navigation. Have you any idea to solve it?

Comment: To prevent the crash, check for `IsBusy` before setting it to `true`, and if it is already `true` just return. You might also need to delay resetting it to `false` until navigation is done.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
_deviceService.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        IsBusy = true;
    });
    //await ... long running process.
```

In above code snippet, _deviceService is of type IDeviceService injected through constructor like below:

```
private IDeviceService _deviceService;

/// <summary>
/// Class constructor 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="deviceService"></param>
public MyPageViewModel(IDeviceService deviceService) {
    _deviceService = deviceService;
}
```

Comment: @Haukinger might be right, that problem occurs cause I try to navigate to another page in my method (when i write on the screen some text it works, but when i navigate it doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Just setting IsBusy doesn't work, because the command doesn't get notified when IsBusy changes, so doesn't the UI. You have to use RaiseCanExecuteChanged to notify everyone. Better way is to just use ObservesCanExecute after creation of the DelegateCommand (Fluent API, but notice that only one property can be observed). It takes care of this for you and will call RaiseCanExecuteChanged automatically.

Here's an example how i usually handle this:

```
public MyViewModel(): ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
    public bool IsBusy { get; set; }

    public ICommand ShowEventDetailsCommand { get; private set; }

    public  MyViewModel(INavigationService navService)
    {
        _navigationService = navService;
        ShowEventDetailsCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(async(obj) => await ExecuteShowEventDetailsCommand(obj)).ObservesCanExecute(() => !IsBusy);
    }

    public async Task ExecuteShowEventDetailsCommand(obj)
    {
        IsBusy = true; // Note this is not thread safe, just for demonstration
        try
        {
            await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(...);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is usually the way i handle this. But notice that the access on IsBusy isn't threadsafe so you should use something that is. I've got something like a LockActivityHandler with .TryLock, .Unlock and .IsLocked.

```
if(LockActivityHandler.TryLock())
{
    try
    {
        //DoStuff
    }
    finally
    {
        LockActivityHandler.Unlock();
    }
}
```

IsLocked can be bound to the Enabled property of UI elements to disable them. Even if those are not disabled and another action is running, the new action would not be executed due to TryLock() => false

PS: This is also written down in the documentation with more examples, so you may take a look here: https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/commanding.html